# Proper way to deserialize multidimensional JSON using JSON.NET in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I was researching during a lot of time about how deserialize this json file:

```
{  
"clients":[  
  {  
     "id":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86",
     "name":"Britney",
     "email":"britneyblankenship@quotezart.com",
     "role":"admin"
  },
  {  
     "id":"e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb",
     "name":"Manning",
     "email":"manningblankenship@quotezart.com",
     "role":"admin"
  },
  {  
     "id":"a3b8d425-2b60-4ad7-becc-bedf2ef860bd",
     "name":"Barnett",
     "email":"barnettblankenship@quotezart.com",
     "role":"user"

     [ ... ]
```

This is my controller code:

```
 using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    receivedData = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

var userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(receivedData);

foreach (User us in userList)
{
   //this method just print the user Id
   MsgBox(u.Id);
}
```

So, I am absolutely stuck because the Json

> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(receivedData); launch the
>   following exception:
>
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InsuranceWebAPI.Models.User]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

I try to set the json data into an array and a list, but doesn't works. 
I know that maybe is a very beginner question but I am not used to work with Json and Json.net

Can any body help me to get the data into an array or List.

Thanks in advance to everybody and sorry if I don't understand properly the other questions about Json.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your JSON format is not of a collection of users. It is of an object containing a property named `clients` which is a collection of users. See this model:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public IEnumerable<User> clients { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
}
```

And by executing this:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText(receivedData));
```

Comment: Works! Buy I can't acces to the data as an array, maybe I asked a different thing excuseme, how can I manipulate the client data inside the data variable, to store it into a class?

Comment: @MadDev - didn't understand current problem

Comment: @MadDev - if you need `clients` to be an array or list, you can change it from `IEnumerable<User>` to `List<User>` or `User[]` and it will still work.

Comment: Forget get it @Gilad Green, Too much hours studying and working today :( you really help me man. A lot of thanks!

Comment: Thats true @Gilad Green, seems that is more convenient to use the IEnumerable, finally the code works fine, now I have problems to populate with the data a TextArea hehehe... but this is another issue... ;-) If you can check it this is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698982/how-to-write-in-a-textarea-from-controller-in-mvc-net

Comment: @MadDev - If this answer helped you solve the problem please consider marking question solved by it.

Comment: @Gilad Green - Yes, thats true... sorry. ;-) but... I so ashamed because I don't know how do it, perhaps just labeling with a solved [SOLVED] tag?

Comment: @MadDev - that's fine :) what you do is on the answer, just below where you see it's votes and can upvote there is a grey V. If you press it it'll turn green and mark question as solved my this answer

Comment: @Gilad Green Oh my god! I can't believe it :( thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Or..

```
        dynamic userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("file.js"));

        foreach (var user in userList.clients)
        {
            ///MessageBox.Show(user.id);
            Console.WriteLine(user.id);
        }
```