# How to write in a TextArea from controller in MVC .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a little application as exercise to learn MVC and ASP.NET, and I have a problem with the following code:

BTW: Sorry... I studied .NET but not ASP, just Windows Forms and nothing about MVC (as a practical way).

This is my **View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("userById", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
   <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
}

<h3>Value results</h3>
@Html.TextArea("results", new { rows = 40, columns = 80 })
```

And I want to fill this TextArea (can be another element) with a Json Data

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult userById()
    {
        string receivedData;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
            .Create("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5808862710000087232b75ac");

        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            receivedData = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(receivedData);

        List<User> userList = data.clients.ToList();

        foreach (var item in userList)
        {
            ViewData["results"] = item.Id;
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

My idea is populate the TextArea with the Json data that are stored into the variable called userList, but the foreach loop just fill ONE element. :( 
Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to display the full json data in the text area as-is?

Comment: Yes, well display just a field, as a grid for example. One per line

Comment: Well if you simply want to show all the json data, then you can remove the foreach loop, avoid the json deserialization and instead `ViewData["results"] = receivedData;`

Answer (score 0):

In your solution in the foreach loop you constantly overwrite value in VeiwBag. You can populate it with JSON directly if that's what you want:

```
ViewData["results"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList);
```

If you want to display users you can users collection to ViewBag:

```
ViewData["results"] = userList;
```

And then in the view build list of users for example:

```
<ul>
    @foreach(var user in ViewData["results"])
    {
        <li>@user.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks by your fast answer, so I need to manipulate the Json Data as Objects and for this I was trying to print the User.Id field using a foreach loop. If I set directly the Json Data to the ViewData["results"] I view all the json. :(

Comment: @MadDev, yes, I first thought you want a json in a view. You do need to manipulate objects deserialized from json and use them in foreach loop.

Comment: I can manipulate objects without problems, in fact I have a List with objects extracted from the json file, but I can show the fields... In fact the problem is very "easy" I just want to show a List in a component (for example the TextArea), but your solutions doesn't works (at least in my case) ;-) I have errors when I tried to manipulate objects in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem with the following code, I will pleasant if anybody have some idea about how can improve it.

**Controller code:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult userById()
    {
        string receivedData;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
            .Create("http://www.amisteriousurl.com");

        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            receivedData = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(receivedData);
        List<User> userList = data.clients.ToList();
        ViewData["results"] = getId(userList);

        return View("Index");
    }

private string getId(List<User> list)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {

            sb.Append(item.Id);
            sb.Append("\n");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

**View:**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

@model InsuranceWebAPI.Models.User

@using (Html.BeginForm("userById", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
   <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
}

<h3>Value results</h3>
@Html.TextArea("results", new { rows = 40, columns = 80 })
```

**Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace InsuranceWebAPI.Models
{
public class RootObject
{
    public IEnumerable<User> clients { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    private string email;
    private string id;
    private string name;
    private string role;

    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(string email, string id, string name, string role)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Role = role;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Role { get; set; }

}
}
```

Thanks to everybody!