# How to deserialize multidimensional JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I know people asked and already got some answers very similar question before [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697885/proper-way-to-deserialize-multidimensional-json-using-json-net-in-c-sharp), but still, I couldn't figure it out about mine. I have a JSON file contains a multidimensional object, like below:

```
{
      "Common": {
        "Required": "Required Entry ",
        "Photos": "Photos",
        "Videos": "Videos",
        "Register": "Register"
      },
      "Forms": {
        "Form": "Forms",
        "Name": "Name",
        "Phone": "Phone",
        "Email": "Email",
        "Message": "Message"
      },
      "Sections": {
        "Home": {
          "EventDateTime": "",
          "MainTitle": "",
          "SubTitle": ""
        },
        "About": {},
        "Venue": {},
        "Schedule": {},
        "Speakers": {},
        "Sponsors": {},
        "Price": {},
        "Contact": {}
      }
    }
```

I would like to deserialize it into my view model (LanguagesViewModel) like this:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class LanguagesViewModel
{
    public Common Common { get; set; }
    public Buttons Buttons { get; set; }
    public Forms Forms { get; set; }
    public Navbar Navbar { get; set; }
    public Sections Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Common
{
    public string Required { get; set; }
    public string Photos { get; set; }
    public string Videos { get; set; }
    public string Register { get; set; }
}

public class Forms
{
    public string Form { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Sections
{
    public Home Home { get; set; }
    public About About { get; set; }
    public Venue Venue { get; set; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    public Speakers Speakers { get; set; }
    public Sponsors Sponsors { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Home
{
    public string EventDateTime { get; set; }
    public string MainTitle { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
}

public class About
{

}

public class Venue
{

}

public class Schedule
{

}

public class Speakers
{

}

public class Sponsors
{

}

public class Price
{

}

public class Contact
{

}
```

}

Some of the snippet to do this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(language_file_path))
{
    string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
    items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LanguagesViewModel>(contents);
}
```

Somehow, I only can get the first level of the objects, which is:

```
LanguagesViewModel{
    Common:null,
    Forms:null,
    Sections:null
}
```

Not the second level, not the third level. Did I do something wrong or have I missed something? Very appreciated for any kind of help.

Thank you.

Comment: If I'm correct, opting in means you need to explicitly say [JsonProperty("yourJsonKeyHere")] on everything you have for .NET to be able to assign the values. Try that out.

Comment: Have you tried this method? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm

Comment: @Train thanks for a very quick reply, just tried what you've suggested and got the same result, it doesn't work.

Comment: I would not recommend usinng `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` if you're planning to deserialize the entire object each time. It doesn't make sense since you're expecting all properties to be deserialized.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Just tried it out and it works for me! thank you very much. one more thing  you may want to know that I didn't put JsonProperty on each of the property in my view model class, but it still works.

Comment: @rhys_stubbs You're right, I use [JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptOut)] instead [JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)] and it works fine as well. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MemberSerialization.htm see here to find more details

Comment: No worries man. Anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use this static class

```
public static class JsonHelper 
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this string content)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Parse(content).GetValue(typeof(T).Name);

        if (obj == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        else
            return obj.ToObject<T>();
        //This ToObject here is default method written in object
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var mymodel= json.ToObject<Forms>();
```

Or create a JSON object and read it with magic strings.

```
//Creating your JSON object
JObject content = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd()//or your json);

//content["your object name"] let you access to you object
var common =(Common)content["Common"];
```

in multidimensional objects, you can access them like this.

```
 //content["level1"]["level2"]["level3"] & ...
 var sections= (Home)content["Sections"]["Home"];
```

Also this way may work but i prefer the way with magic strings.

```
dynamic jsonObject = new JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
var common = jsonObject.Common;
```

You can find more in [this link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

I hope this Helps!

Comment: It's better to use attributes at the model level in a central location. This would get really messy if he used it like this in multiple places.

Comment: @Train You are right.but in some case it is hard to have access to classes. previously I have experience with working with one API that returns a huge amount of data that only I need 10 percent of the properties. but implementing classes for all of them consumes more time and makes it program complex for nothing. but if this is gonna used in multiple places as you say its better to use attributes.

Comment: In that case, create an extension method, to keep it in a central location.

Comment: @ShervinIvari This way may looks cleaner but I think using IntelliSense is much more convenient and safe than type.

Comment: @Jack I update my answer as you say, just call ToObject the rest will function do and also you will have IntelliSense menu!

Comment: @ShervinIvari That's great! I'm using Reflection, but yours more effective. Thank you and I'm gonna take this as an answer.

Comment: @Jack Anytime jack! Also, you can use children function in jobject to access the children and parent.in this case I think is useless but its good to know if in the feature you need to develop.